# Disable item overflow in Vaadin Flow MenuBar for auto-width grid column

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

In my Vaadin Flow Grid I have a column with auto-width set to `true` and flex grow `0`. In that column I add a `MenuBar` with two items. The menu is always collapsed to the `...` overflow button. How can I prevent the overflow in this case? I want to always show the menu items in that column.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to set definitive width to MenuBar which is wide enough to accomodate two menu buttons.

Comment: @TatuLund This would be an approximazation but no exact solution. The menu item contains a text that depends on language so I cannot really set a definitive width.